# Numeric addresses in assembly language

Tags: assembly

Why would it not be a good idea to use numeric addresses when writing instructions that access variables? I have been studying assembly language and this question is one I have had a problem with.

Comment: You have to explain better what "numeric addresses" mean. Do you mean tell the program which exact address to use for a variable?

Comment: An assembler generates numeric addresses or offsets when it assembles a program, so the question is not clear. If you mean fixed addresses, then there are some platforms where I/O is memory mapped and those are  fixed addresses (use equates or defines in assembly source). There may also be some fixed addresses for things like interrupt vector tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numeric addresses ties you to specific locations in memory.  Normally applications can be loaded anywhere in memory, so it won't work if it's loaded in a different place than you assumed when you programmed it.  Even if you are programming an operating system kernel that lives in low memory, a new version of the kernel may cause data or code below your address to be bigger or smaller, in which case you'd have to change all your numeric addresses.

Most processors these days are just as fast with indirect addresses as with direct addresses, so using numeric addresses doesn't help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This would only work for boot loaders. You never know what address would your code be loaded at, even under DOS.

Also, numeric addresses change if you insert as much as one line between the referenced point (variable, label, whatever) and the point of usage. It's a pain to maintain.

Comment: While the concern is real, we don't even know that the code in question is going to be run on a platform which *has* an operating system, or one with a variable load address.  And IIRC DOS also supported a fixed address (within segment), flat binary format conceptually compatible to that used in predecessor CP/M.

Comment: The OP mentioned they were **studying**. A student of x86 assembly won't be targeting a a scary OS-less, anything-goes environment.

Comment: Where do you see x86?  How do you know the class, even if it is based on x86, is targeting an operating system?  I must say the only class I ever had that touched x86 assembly was mostly bare-metal, but briefly started with .com binaries on DOS before moving to the OS-less embedded development boards.

Comment: Good point. Mental crosstalk on my part, probably :) Anyway, my second point stands.